# PHP Offset Error

Tags: php, drupal, offset

I'm running into a PHP error that through all of my scrummaging around the internet - I have been unable to crack as of yet.

The error says:

`Error message
Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in include() (line 89 of /home/devced/public_html/site/sites/all/themes/cedncsu/page.tpl.php).`

So, looking around my code, I currently have (actual use commented below):

```
<?php
    // Get Base URL
    global $base_url;

    // Get the Page's Parent Menu Item
    $menuParent = menu_get_active_trail();

    // Since it returns an array, make sure to target what you are looking for
    // You should print_r what menu_get_active_trail() to see what else it gives you
    $menuParent = $menuParent[1]['link_title'];
    $menuParent = strtolower(str_replace( " ", "-", $menuParent));
    $menuParent = preg_replace('/[^\w\d_ -]/si', '', $menuParent);

    // Generate class specific for department page headers
    $menuParentDepartment = menu_get_active_trail();
    $menuParentDepartment = $menuParentDepartment[3]['link_title']; // This is where they say the error is
    $menuParentDepartment = strtolower(str_replace( " ", "-", $menuParentDepartment));
    $menuParentDepartment = preg_replace('/[^\w\d_ -]/si', '', $menuParentDepartment);

    // Current Page space replace/lowercase
    $currentTitle = strtolower(str_replace( " ", "-", $title));
    $currentTitle = preg_replace('/[^\w\d_ -]/si', '', $currentTitle);
?>
```

I think this is a general coding practice that I'm missing, but have thus-far been stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply: `$menuParentDepartment[3]` is not defined.  You need to make sure that the index (or as PHP calls it, offset) exists before you try to index it.  Use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Comment: +1 , @Zach are you sure that menu_get_active_trail() always returns 3 or more than 3 array elements ?

Comment: Sweet! Yup @kantu, that makes perfect sense "why" it would be showing the error - because that is not always the case, so if I check to see if a value is in that 3rd position or not first, then running those other parts would be useless in the other cases. Thanks for the help!